# In "for article, slug in public.articles._data" what is "slug"? Is there a way to use nesting arrays?

Tags: json, node.js, pug, harp

I experiment with HarpJS, a NodeJS static blog generator. In tutorials there is such example for metadata:

```
for article, slug in public.articles._data
 a(href="/articles/#{ slug }")
  h2= article.title
```

and `_data.json` file:

```
{
 "hello-world": {  <-- available everywhere as public.articles._data
  "title": "Hello World.",
  "date": "2013-02-28"
 },
 "hello-brazil": {
  "title": "Hello Brazil.",
  "date": "2013-03-04"
 }
}
```

If I understand right `for article` takes every high level object and we can get title with `article.title` or date with `article.date`. But what is `slug`? Is it the predefined variable in Jade/HarpJs? If so, are there others, or did I get the concept wrong? I couldn't find any information on this topic, if there is a good article to read I would appreciate it. Thank you.

As @Brennan suggests in comments the second argument could be an index. Simple substitution and renaming of variables `article` and `slug` proves that. But there is one more problem. Please consider this example:

```
{
 "hello-world": {
  "title": "Hello World.",
  "date": "2013-02-28",
  "test": {
    "testContent": "123"
  }
 },
 "hello-brazil": {
  "title": "Hello Brazil.",
  "date": "2013-03-04"
 }
}


for s, a in public.articles._data
 a(href="/articles/#{ a }")
  h2= s.title
  h3= s.date
  h3= a
  - var obj =  s.test
  h3= obj
  h3= obj.testContent
```

This code gives error during the compilation. If I comment the very last line it works though. And I can't substitute last line with snippet from the docs:

```
each val, index in obj
  h1=index + ': ' + val
```

There are no nesting and two-dimensional arrays?

Comment: You're right the [documentation](http://harpjs.com/docs/development/rules) is lacking.  I'm not totally convinced this would work.  According to [this](http://jade-lang.com/reference/iteration/) jade only supports `each` and `while` constructs.  In other languages, the 2nd argument in a for..in loop will be the `index`.  It's possible that's the case here, but I can't find any concrete documentation.

Comment: Thank you @Brennan ! This approach has comprehensible logic. I edited the question, would you please read it? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hey @Georgy, I would be surprised if there wasn't nesting in jade.  Will you post the error you're getting?  I'm also not sure how the template will react when `s.test` is undefined in the `hello-brazil` object.

Comment: @Brennan your guess that the problem is with _s.test is undefined in the hello-brazil object._ is right, everything works fine if it is defined. Would you please write the answer so I could mark it as a solution? I appreciate your time and care, thank you once again.

Comment: happy to help!  I'm glad we got it worked out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer the original question see my comment:

> The documentation is lacking. I'm not totally convinced this would work. According to this jade only supports each and while constructs. In other languages, the 2nd argument in a for..in loop will be the index. It's possible that's the case here, but I can't find any concrete documentation

The second question was an issue with the mock object.

Looks like you need a check to be sure that your property is defined in your mockdata, or do some checking to be sure the property you expect, exists.

Answer (score 1):

Following example probably answers the question:

```
<h1><%= title %></h1>
<ul>
  <% for (var slug in public.posts._data) { %>
    <% var post = public.posts._data[slug] %> 
    <li>
      <a href="posts/<%= slug %>">
        <%= post.title %>
      </a>
    </li>
  <% } %>
</ul>
```